# Can I say independent components of ICA are also linear independent?

Tags: independent-component-analysis

In other words, does the independent components form a vector basis?

EDIT:Let'me try to clarify the question

If I calculate $n$ independent components for a given set of $n$ dimensional observations, are those  components also linearly independent (property required to form a vector basis)?

Comment: You should be able to reconstruct the original data out of the data projected onto the components. So yes, unless you have some seriously degenerate data, in which case I don't know what the algorithm will spit out.

Comment: May we presume that "ICA" refers to [independent components analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) and not one of a [hundred other possible meanings of this acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICA)?  But where you mention a "vector basis," to which space are you referring?

Comment: Yes, by ICA I refer to Independent Component Analysis. Let'me clarify the question.

Comment: Suppose, to see what can happen, there is a *single* actual signal that is being picked up by $n$ observers. If these observers are perfect, you can solve the problem using just *one* component. If you calculate $n\gt 1$ components, what solution does your algorithm give you? For another useful thought experiment, what happens when this set of observations has less than full rank (*i.e.*, does not span a space of $n$ dimensions)?